# Why I am getting the maximum recursion depth exceeded error in an f-string in python?

Tags: python

I am getting the maximum recursion depth error which originates in an f-string. I am a newbie in Python and am not getting what's going wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Also, guide me if I am writing the constructor properly?

```
class NearEarthObject:
    """This class represents a near earth object"""
    def __init__(self, designation, name, diameter, hazardous, approaches):
        designation = designation
        name = name
        diameter = diameter
        hazardous = hazardous
        approaches = approaches
        self.fullname = designation + "(" + name + ")"
        if len(name) == 0:
            self.fullname = designation

    @property
    def designation(self):
        return self.designation

    @designation.setter
    def designation(self, designation):
        self.designation = designation

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name

    @name.setter
    def name(self,name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self.diameter

    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self,diameter):
        self.diameter = diameter

    @property
    def hazardous(self):
        return self.hazardous

    @hazardous.setter
    def hazardous(self, hazardous):
        self.hazardous = hazardous

    @property
    def approaches(self):
        return self.approaches

    @approaches.setter
    def approaches(self, approaches):
        self.approaches = approaches

    def __str__(self):
        return f'NEO {self.fullname} has a diameter of {self.diameter:.3f} ' \
            f'km and {"is" if self.hazardous == True else "is not"} potentially hazardous'
```

The exception traceback is here:
[image: Exception traceback]

Comment: What is the object type of `self.diameter`?

Comment: It should probably include the code to call the function and reproduce the error.

Comment: The error is quite obvious, `self.diameter` returns `self.diameter` which returns `self.diameter`... Properties need a storage, e.g. `self._diameter`, look at the examples: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your properties are all written in a a way that will cause infinite recursion if you access them because you are using the same name for the *property* as you are for the underlying *attribute*

for example for the property diameter:

```
@property
def diameter(self):
    return self.diameter
```

if you run the code

```
print(object.diameter)
```

when it tries to determine the value of `object.diameter` it will run the `diameter(self)` function which then tries to determine the value of the `self.diameter` which again invokes the `diameter(self)` function, which tries to determine the value of `self.diameter`, etc etc until you reach recursion limit

When you create a *property* (eg. `diameter`) you need to pick a **new** name for the actual *attribute*.  A common choice is to use the same name with a single underscore in front of it. eg. `_diameter` so your diameter property would be re-written as:

```
@property
def diameter(self):
     """provide the value of the diameter property by returning
        the underlying _diameter attribute"""
     return self._diameter
```

then you would also need to change your `__init__` function to set the `_diameter` attribute.

Additionally you could also create writable versions of your properties, in which case you would NOT need to change your `__init__()`.  You can create the readable and writable properties like this:

```
# create the readable property first

@property
def diameter(self):
     """provide the value of the diameter property by returning
        the underlying _diameter attribute"""
     return self._diameter

# then use the newly created diameter property's setter attribute
# to decorate a second function WITH THE SAME NAME which will be
# the setter

@diameter.setter  
def diameter(self, new_diameter):
    """write to the diameter property by updating the value of
       the underlying _diameter attribute"""
    _diameter = new_diameter
```